# Is machine epsilon the largest relative error in representing a number as a floating point number?

Tags: computer-architecture

Is machine epsilon the largest relative error in representing a number as a floating point number?

There are so many definitions of machine epsilon. I'm starting to get confused.
Isn't the machine epsilon the smallest?

Comment: There are nonequivalent definitions of what people call *machine epsilon*. What can we do? You need to ask whoever you are talking with or try to deduce from the context.

Answer (score 1):

In the *most common* usage, and in particular in IEEE-754, machine epsilon is the smallest number $\epsilon$ such that $1 + \epsilon \ne 1$.

It does have an interpretation in terms of relative distance between numbers: It is the largest relative separation of two consecutive normal numbers.

There are a couple of important points to understand here:

- This is only about *normal* numbers, as opposed to *subnormal* numbers (i.e. what older standards called "denormal numbers").
- It is about *consecutive* numbers, namely, some floating point number and its closest neighbour.
- Machine epsilon measures *separation*, not *error*. It is the relative distance between those floating-point numbers, not the relative error between a floating point number and anything.

So if $x_1$ and $x_2$ are consecutive normal numbers, then:

$$0.5\epsilon \le \frac{|x_2 - x_1|}{\max(|x_1|,|x_2|)} \le \epsilon$$

So if you have a candidate real number, and you want to represent it as a floating-point number, how bad can the relative error be?

As gnasher729 rightly pointed out, it can be as large as you want if the real number would overflow, underflow, or be subnormal. But assuming that it's in a reasonable range, meaning that it is between two consecutive normal numbers, then one of those normal numbers is within $0.5\epsilon$ of it in a relative sense.

Because this is a fraught definition, the term that we usually use is "units of last place", or "ulp" for short. If a real number is within the normal number range, there is a floating point number whose error is at most 0.5ulp.

Comment: That’s an unusual definition of machine epsilon. Much more common: “Machine epsilon is the difference from 1 to the next larger floating point number”. Which is almost twice as large. 1+eps > 1 if eps is slightly larger than half of machine epsilon.

Comment: That's fair. This is the way that it was originally explained to me, but now that I think about it, it's actually the smallest number such that 1 + epsilon != 1 and (1 + epsilon) - 1 == epsilon.

Answer (score 0):

If you read "machine epsilon" you really need to look up the definition that your book uses for it. It is all over the place. I’d define it as “difference between 1 and the next larger floating point number”, alternatively “the value of the least significant bit of a floating point number between 1 and 2”. Let’s call this number u for short.

"The largest relative error" is very unlikely to be the "machine epsilon": All computers including tablets and phones in my possession have floating point arithmetic following the IEEE 754 Standard, and there the largest possible relative error is -1 or +1: Let d be the value of the least significant bit of a denormalised numbers, then a result of d/2 would be rounded to 0 for a relative error of -1; a result just a tiny bit larger than d/2 would be rounded to d, for a relative error close to 1.

For normalised results, rounding to nearest, if 2^k <= x <= 2 * 2^k then numbers are 2^k * u apart. The absolute rounding error is up to 1/2 2^k * u. If x = m * 2^k with 1 <= m <= 2, then the relative error is at most (1 / 2m) * u. This means results slightly less than a power of two have lower bounds for the relative error. This can be used if you calculate something like a * b * c: Sometimes you can rearrange the order of operations to reduce the bounds for the rounding error.

There are implementations like IBM’s “long double” on POWER where machine epsilon makes little sense.